# Javascript ES2015 import throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, node.js, material-design, firebase-hosting

I have a website hosted on Firebase hosting. I would like to add material theming to it(Buttons, Textfields, etc...). So, I ran the command `npm install --save @material/textfield`. I then extracted the folder called `@material` to my styles directory so that the structure looked like this:

```
Root
|
+---index.html
+---scripts/
    +---app.js
+---styles/
    +---main.css
    +---@material/
        +---……
```

I can reference css files from my `main.css` by adding `@import "@material/textfield/dist/mdc.textfield.css";` to the start of my stylesheet. This correctly changes the styling of the button. However, when I go to do the same thing for js, it doesn't work.

According to Material Design's Github Repo, I should just be able to add

```
import {MDCTextField} from '@material/textfield';
const textField = new MDCTextField(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field'));
```

to the top of my script. However, when I deploy the code, and look at the console, the following error is returned: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. I have tried to `require()` the files, and change the path to `import {MDCRipple} from '../styles/@material/ripple/dist/mdc.ripple.js';`. This throws the same error. If I do: `import * as MDCRipple from '../styles/@material/ripple/dist/mdc.ripple.js';`, the same error is also thrown(except instead of the "{" character, it does not expect the "*" character).

This was supposed to be an easy conversion for my site, but it has given my tons of headaches. What am I doing wrong?

BTW: I know that the files the import statement is using exist. Also, isn't Node.js server-side?

Comment: Import/export is only available behind a flag on the newest version. If you want to use these files on a older version of node your gonna have to transpirel them.

Comment: how do I update to the newest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download latest version of node: https://nodejs.org/en/

Version 8.11.2 LTS will work.

The --experimental-modules flag can be used to enable features for ES2015 import. More information:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/api/esm.md